# Python - Split by comma skipping the content inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex, replace

I need to split a string by commas, but I have a problem with this case:

```
TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME)), SECOND , THIRD
```

I would like to split and get:

```
var[0] = "TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME))"
var[1] = "SECOND"
var[2] = "THIRD"
```

Thank you

Comment: So the problem is that not all of the commas in the string should be split on? How do you differentiate between those that should and those that shouldn't? Is it the parentheses? Where has this string come from, and why doesn't it use e.g. quoting to distinguish? In you want to `re.split` your specific example could use something like `,(?!.*\))` (i.e. a comma with no closing parentheses following it), but that may not work in the general case.

Comment: You need to do it by traditional for loop.

Comment: For the general case of matching nested parentheses (or tags or whatever), you need to write a real parser:  tokenize the input, then parse it according to your grammar.

Comment: `var.split(',')` works for u ?

Comment: The string comes from a website (I can't modify). I tried to use re.split but I couldn't find the correct regex.

Comment: Or split it by parentheses too and then join it ?

Comment: @Onilol have you actually read the question? And it's *"you"*, please.

Comment: @David until you can describe unambiguously which commas should be split on and which shouldn't, you won't be able to tell a computer how to do it. If you've tried things that didn't work, please show them so that others don't have to try the same things.

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually I did. He didn't specify he had problems with the parentheses string since on both fragments of code he repeated all the strings and I really think you should only comment on useful stuff instead of getting worried by a grammar alteration on a comment ( if it were an answer I would agree with u ) :)

Comment: @Onilol what? The example output clearly shows it *not* being split on all of the commas, so `var.split(',')` couldn't possibly work, and putting it back together afterwards has the same problem as splitting in the first place if you don't know which commas are relevant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the regex. It's just what I need.

Comment: @David If Jonsharpe's regex was the correct answer, I'd encourage you to ask him to post it and accept his posting, or if he doesn't want to accept your own replication of his work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
,(?!(?:[^(]*\([^)]*\))*[^()]*\))
```

This regex is finding a comma with an assertion that makes sure comma is not in parentheses. This is done using a negative lookahead that first consumes all matching `(` and `)` and then a `)`. **This assumes parentheses are balanced and unescaped**.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yP6yN4/2)

**Code:**

```
>>> s = 'TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME)), SECOND , THIRD'
print re.split(r',(?!(?:[^(]*\([^)]*\))*[^()]*\))', s)

['TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME))', ' SECOND ', ' THIRD']
```

Or:

```
>>> s = 'TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS, IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME)), SECOND , THIRD'
>>> print re.split(r',(?!(?:[^(]*\([^)]*\))*[^()]*\))', s)
['TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS, IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME))', ' SECOND ', ' THIRD']
```

Comment: Good grief that's an ugly regex! Could you at least explain it?

Comment: I know it is ugly looking due to many `(` and `)`. I tried to explain it in the answer though.

Comment: This should have been selected as the answer. This regex work with general cases also to ignore the commas within parentheses.

Comment: Note, that it will not work when there is an item before the first. For example 'FIRST, TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS, IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME)), SECOND , THIRD' . In this case, the first Element will be "FIRST, TEXT EXAMPLE (...)" and not be split.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple parser approach that works for your example:

```
def top_level_split(s):
    """
    Split `s` by top-level commas only. Commas within parentheses are ignored.
    """

    # Parse the string tracking whether the current character is within
    # parentheses.
    balance = 0
    parts = []
    part = ''

    for c in s:
        part += c
        if c == '(':
            balance += 1
        elif c == ')':
            balance -= 1
        elif c == ',' and balance == 0:
            parts.append(part[:-1].strip())
            part = ''

    # Capture last part
    if len(part):
        parts.append(part.strip())

    return parts

my_list = top_level_split("TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME)), SECOND , THIRD")
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **jonrsharpe** :

```
text = "TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME)), SECOND , THIRD"
array = re.split(r',(?!.*\))', text)
for item in array:
    # Print and remove the first space
    print item.strip(" ")
```

Result:

```
TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME))
SECOND
THIRD
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just use `rsplit`:

```
l1 = "TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME)), SECOND , THIRD".rsplit(",", 2)

for line in l1:
   print line

TEXT EXAMPLE (THIS IS (A EXAMPLE, BUT NOT WORKS, FOR ME))
SECOND
THIRD
```