# Split string by commas except when in bracket

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split a string by commas except when in the bracket but my problem is when I have instead brackets

here is an example:

```
b='hi, this(me,(you)) , hello(a,b)'
re.split(r',(?![^\(]*[\)])', b)
['hi', ' this(me', '(you)) ', ' hello(a,b)']
```

what I expect is:

`['hi', ' this(me,(you))',' hello(a,b)']`

I have seen similar questions to what I want but it does not work like what I expect I don't know why

1- [Split string at commas except when in bracket environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808913/split-string-at-commas-except-when-in-bracket-environment/26809037)

2- [Python - Split by comma skipping the content inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527245/python-split-by-comma-skipping-the-content-inside-parentheses)

any help?

Comment: Your 1 link posted will have your answer, but if you notice, their brackets are `{` while yours are `(`. Can you modify the answer given there to make it work for you? Spend some time reading the code provided in the answer.

Comment: yes I have modified it but still not work @paritosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using pattern `(?!\S\)|\()`

**Ex:**

```
import re

b = ['hi, this(me,(you)) , hello(a,b)', 'hi, this(me,(you))']
for i in b:
    print(re.split(r',(?!\S\)|\()', i))
```

**Output:**

```
['hi', ' this(me,(you)) ', ' hello(a,b)']
['hi', ' this(me,(you))']
```

Comment: what if I have more than two brackets? like: hi(a,(b, c(d,e)))

Comment: how can I make it skip any commas inside and take the last ")"

Answer (score 1):

If the main text groups are all separated by a comma with a space, then you can use `re.split`:

```
import re
b='hi, this(me,(you)) , hello(a,b)'
result = re.split(',\s', b)
```

Output:

```
['hi', 'this(me,(you)) ', 'hello(a,b)']
```

However, you can also use recursion to parse the string:

```
def parse(d):
  if (v:=next(d, None)) is not None and v != ')':
     yield v if v != '(' else f'({"".join(parse(d))})'
     yield from parse(d)

r, c, l = list(filter(lambda x:x != ',', parse(iter(re.findall('\w+|\(|\)|,', b))))), '', []
for i in r:
   if not i.endswith(')'):
      l.append(c)
      c = i
   else:
      l.append(c+i)
      c = ''

l.append(c)
final_result = list(filter(None, l))
```

Output:

```
['hi', 'this(me,(you))', 'hello(a,b)']
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach without regular expressions could be something like that:

```
b='hi, this(me,(you))'

phrase = ''
phrases = []

in_parenth = 0

for l in b:

    if l == '(':
        in_parenth += 1
    elif l == ')':
        in_parenth -= 1

    if l == ',' and in_parenth == 0:
        if phrase.strip():
            phrases.append(phrase)
        phrase = ''
    else:
        phrase += l

if phrase.strip():
    phrases.append(phrase)

print(phrases)
```

Comment: but it does not split the words, I want to split by a comma because I will count the number of words and it there is ( mean that the words connect

Comment: You wrote that you want to split a string by commas not to split the words and in your example each word is separated by comma. It would be helpful to make it more clear if you want.